# Getting execution time just before Action exit in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have an Action as follows that I am trying to track down the execution time in order to eliminate the delay:

```
 public JsonResult DoSomething(IncidentReportSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
 {
    //search database with searchCriteria
    //get the data, do something with it
    //return success in JSON format
    return Json(new { success = true });
 }
```

Are there any tools in VS2010 to find out how long it takes for Action DoSomething to finish executing? In other words, just before the last `}`

I write the times to the log, but there is a delay after writing the end time to the log and `}`. Bandwidth is not the issue since I am not returning much as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an action filter to measure the executing time.

```
public class ProfileAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   private StopWatch timer;

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExceutingContext filterContext)
   {
      timer = StopWatch.StartNew();
   }

   public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
      timer.Stop();
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("Action method elapsed time: " + timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds.ToString());
   }
}

[Profile]
public JsonResult DoSomething(IncidentReportSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
}
```